# How do I create a text wrapper for the kernel?

Tags: c, osdev

I studied the content from the osdev.org website and built a compiler, launched a test kernel, but I thought, how can I create a primitive text shell for the kernel with commands? Maybe someone can explain to me with an example how to implement this. There is nothing interesting on the site itself, of course there is an article but it is useless for me. I'm a beginner if that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I create a primitive text shell for the kernel with commands?

The correct way is:

- Write enough kernel code to manage various resources (memory, IRQs, IO ports, DMA channels, ...). This should include managing time (a scheduler), and should also include some kind of inter-process communication (so that the scheduler can be told "Don't give this task any more CPU time until/unless it receives data from inter-process communication").
- Enumerate devices, determine each device's resources, and start drivers for whichever devices you find. Note that this is hierarchical. For example, if you enumerate PCI buses and find 2 USB controllers attached to PCI buses and start their device drivers, then you'll need to enumerate each of the USB controllers to find any USB devices attached to USB buses and might find 3 USB hubs, and then you'll need to enumerate all 3 USB hubs to see what is plugged into them. All of this should be coordinated by some kind of "device manager" which keeps track of a hierarchical tree of devices, so that (e.g.) if a device is unplugged or sent to a power saving state (or if its device driver crashes) you can inform drivers that depended on that device (e.g. if a USB hub is unplugged you can inform all drivers for devices that were attached to that hub).
- write keyboard device driver/s. These should decode the data from the device (likely using tables and other information describing a "keyboard layout" that's loaded from file system) and send packets of data using the kernel's inter-process communication (so that any task can say "don't give me any CPU time until I receive data from the keyboard driver"). This will involve designing a standard way that all keyboard drivers (and all software emulating a keyboard - e.g. "on screen keyboard" for people using touchscreens, etc) will behave (e.g. the format of that data packet they send, etc); and probably should involve creating a formal "keyboard device driver interface" specification for your OS to describe whatever you designed (in addition to designing a file format for "keyboard layout files").
- write video device driver/s. This will also include designing a suitable video driver interface for your OS (and should including writing a formal specification describing it). However; video is complex and you can cheat by only designing part of the video driver interface and leaving the rest of it (video mode setting, 3D, GPGPU, ...) until later. The same applies to the video driver itself - you will want to start with "generic raw frame buffer driver" (that just uses a frame buffer configured by the boot loader) and probably won't write actual drivers for specific video cards.
- (optional) write some kind of upper layer to control which task is the main task for each set of user input/output devices. This allows the user to have multiple virtual consoles and switch between them (e.g. maybe with "control+alt+F1" to "control+alt+F12"), possibly allowing some virtual consoles to be associated with terminals and others to be associated with different GUIs. It can also make it easy to support "multiple seat" (e.g. if there's 2 keyboards and 2 monitors, then you can have 2 completely separate users with each user having one keyboard and one monitor).
- create a task with a simple main loop that uses inter-process communication ("don't give me any more CPU time until/unless I receive data from the keyboard") and processes the data it received to build up a current command string, then (if/when the user presses the enter key) parses the command string and does whatever the command says. Note that if you get this far it's tempting to do a tiny little bit of extra work to support user-space, and make it a normal process instead of a kernel task.

The incorrect way is:

- don't have a kernel that supports some/most of the things that device drivers and other code must rely on
- don't do any kind of device enumeration. Instead, make wild assumptions about which devices are present and which resources they use.
- don't put any thought into device driver interfaces. Just slap together whatever seemed convenient (and continually break everything whenever you change any device driver).
- don't use tasks (or inter-process communication). Instead, build the "shell" into the keyboard driver's IRQ handler to make sure the entire OS "pauses" when someone enters any time consuming command.
- don't continue working on the OS after you get the shell to "work". This will be necessary because the code will be too inflexible and too fragile (any attempt to do anything else will cause you to have to rewrite everything).

Note: In my experience people that ask questions like "how do I write a kernel shell" are likely to have skipped everything that matters (because they'd know how to write a shell if they've done everything that a shell depends on); and are so focused on having a shell that they're very tempted to do it all the incorrect way (and then get stuck later and regret it).